Plot a combined stacked and clustered bar graph showing mutually- and non-mutually exclusive data in R
I am looking to make a stacked bar graph showing mutually exclusive categories of data. One of these categories should be further broken down into non-mutually exclusive sub-categories. I feel this breakdown would best be displayed as a clustered bar chart, so the final graph should look something like this:

This is essentially a combination of the two below graphs:
A stacked bar chart, showing the mutually exclusive component

and a clustered bar chart showing the non-mutually exclusive component.

I have looked widely online (e.g. on the R graph gallery), but have not found a similar example made by others.  I believe the solution in ggplot2 may involve facet_wrap, but I have been unable to work out how to simulate this.
I understand that this is probably not a recommended type of data visualisation – as it could be misunderstood by non-expert viewers. However, this graph will be for use in a team of statisticians, and we feel it would fit our needs better than alternatives.
Raw data

Context
This graph is to present questionnaire results showing how many organisations record particular data items about their clients. The 3 mutually exclusive categories correspond to organisations that 1) do record each data item, 2) don't record a data item, and 3) those organisations which didn't complete our questionnaire (recorded, not recorded, and no questionnaire response received). I would like to break the ‘recorded’ category down further to show which age groups the data items are recorded for – i.e. into non-mutually exclusive categories. A standard stacked bar chart would be meaningless for this, hence the need for a combined stacked and clustered graph.
*** Note: context and data adjusted from real-life example to preserve anonymity.
